# Asp.net Web API oAuth2 Authenticate users from two different databases

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity, asp.net-web-api2, restful-authentication

Converting our Web Service based project to Web API based with oAuth 2.0.
API will be accessed from clients and as well as from Company staff (Employees) through web front-end.

Clients and employees both are in different databases.

Right now i setup API for clients, authenticating them with Asp.Net Identity and oAuth 2.0 and getting Bearer token. This setup is working well.

The problematic part is, how do i authenticate employees too (who are in different database) for the same API, same end points?

Can i use two different Identity Providers in same project?
If yes, then how?
Or any other approach?

Can not merge client and employees in single table as both have different set of fields.

Please guide me to right direction.